# C representing any object (type void *) as the integer number (calculated identifier)

Tags: c, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I need to implement **hash table** (or hash map) that stores keys of any type. So I have used `void *key` and `size_t key_size`. I need to write **hash_function(void *key, size_t key_size)** for such keys.

Hash function need to calculate index in the array. So I need in the first place to calculate integer representation of such object. If this will be the string I could get ascii number for each char in the string and sum them up. But I this can be any type (any pointer) i.e. pointer to string pointer to struct how can I calculate such integer representation?

Maybe I could convert this `void *` into `char *` and then loop through key_size bytes?

```
static int hash_function(void *key, size_t key_size) {

        unsigned int h = 0; 
        char *key_data = (char *) key; 

        for(int i=0; i < key_size; i++) { 
             h += key_data[i];  
        }

        return (h * 1049) & HASHTAB_MASK; // HASHTAB_MASK = HASHTAB_SIZE - 1 used instead of modulo operation as such approach is faster
}
```

Comment: This design simply doesn't work. There's no hash function that applies to all types, just like there's no equality predicate that applies to all types, even if you have a length parameter to work with.

Comment: Are you asking whether the code you present is valid?  Yes it is, provided only that `key_size` is no larger than the size of the object to which `key` points and also no larger than `INT_MAX + 1`.

Comment: Why? Couldn't I get given type convert it to binary representation, add each byte and calculate some number and then multiply by prime number and modulo the result by hash table size?

Comment: Will be it a good hash function?

Comment: @MichałZiobro, the question is not whether you can compute the function, but rather whether it is an appropriate hash function for any given data type.  That depends on the data type, but probably no, it's characteristics will not be very good.

Comment: What can be improved, and why it's characteristics wan't be very good? For char * (string) it will add ASCII codes, for struct name* or int * it will add bytes? I am right?

Comment: For one thing, if the objects you hash contain pointers then you will hash the pointer values, not the data they point to.  You will also hash any padding bytes in the objects, which is probably a deal-breaker for any type that *has* padding.  On the more technical side, your function is insentive to reordering of the bytes of the object, which is not a good characteristic for a hash function.

Comment: Your best bet for a generic hash table is for it to have a function pointer to the hash function it should call. There's a reason why hash tables in other languages use an external hash function.

Comment: ok so I should define in hash_map filed that will store hash function pointer, and initialize it with specific hash function for the type that will be placed in the hash_map keys, e.g. if I will be using string keys I should hash_map_init( str_hash_func ), if keys will be integers I should call hash_map_init( int_hash_func ), etc. ?

Comment: also, don't use `& HASH_MASK`, but use `% HASHTAB_SIZE` instead. If the HASHTAB_SIZE is power of 2 then the compiler would optimise '%' into bitwise-and automatically. Also, the hash-tables of odd (preferably prime) size show better results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual answer here is to have the caller of the `insert` function to provide their own hash function, like so:

```
void insert(struct hash_table* table, void* data, int (*hash_function)(void*)) {
    int hash = hash_function(data);
    // insert data...
}
```

Then you can implement a hash function for each type you want to insert, and pass it to the `insert` function:

```
void hash_string(void* data) {
    char* s = (char*)s;
    // hash the string...
}

// somewhere else
insert(&table, "Hello, world!", &hash_string);
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, because you can't resolve collisions with just a hash function, especially if you're allowing mixed key types in the same table.

Comment: @user2357112 This is an oversimplified example, please excuse me for not adding a key parameter.